# Least number of ways to color a map using at most 4 colors

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Given all the maps with k regions, consider the map(s) that can be colored in the least amount of possible ways. In how many ways can it be colored (n)? (using at most 4 colors and not counting different permutations of the colors.)

Is there an integer sequence? I couldn't find it. I must have missed it.

Here is a map with 4 regions that can only be colored in one way.

[image: map with 4 regions]

And here is one with 5 regions, only one way to color it.

[image: map with 5 regions]

The sequence goes like this:

1,1,1,1,1,...

I don't know the answer for a map with 6 regions.

Comment: Let's focus on the planar dual graph. Your graphs $G_n$ have the property that each face is a triangle, and $G_n$ has a unique coloring (up to relabeling colors). Now form $G_{n+1}$ by taking one of the triangular regions and subdividing it by placing a vertex in the center. You already know there's only one coloring on $G_n$ up to permutation; now the color on the new vertex is forced on you, so there's only $1$ coloring of $G_{n+1}$. This is in fact exactly what you did in passing from $G_4$ to $G_5$.

Comment: All those graphs have chromatic polynomial $k(k-1)(k-2)(k-3)^{n-4}$, which evaluates to $24$ at $k=4$; but those are just the $24$ permutations of the colors, so essentially just one way to color.

Comment: This does not answer your question, but it is [known that there are exponentially many $5$-list colorings of planar graphs](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=2325797). There are [also](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=4268692) other [related](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/article?mr=4513826) results.

Comment: The graphs defined by mme are sometimes called Apollonian graphs and are uniquely the only class of simple planar graph with exactly one 4-colouring (up to exchange of colours).  See the Wikipedia article "Apollonian network".  Note that they all contain a vertex of degree 3 (the last one added) so the question remains of what is the least number of colourings when the minimum degree is 4 or 5.  Probably this has been studied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one with 6 regions, only one way to color it (F in red sorry for the quality) :

[image]

Comment: This is the same example as mme gave in a comment.